# How to load data with missing values from text file in matlab?

Tags: matlab, missing-data

If my data looks like this:

```
1 8 9 3 4 
2 5 6 7
3 1 2
4 1
5 2
6 2
7 2
8 1 
9 1
```

In matlab, how can I load it into a matrix with missing values represented by 0 or NaN?
Additionally, the number of columns and rows are unknown.

Comment: Does it have to be a matrix? Could they be stored in a cell?

Comment: I assume that you are starting from a file?

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
text = fileread('file.txt');

lines = strread(text, '%s','delimiter','\n');

for l = 1:length(lines)
    lines{l} = str2num(cell2mat(lines(l)));
end
```

It reads in file.txt as a string, breaks it into individual lines (stored in a cell), converts each line to a matrix and stores the matrix back in the cell.